Exporting 3-D Farfield Plot Images in CST Studio Suite
I'm working on a VBA script for CST Studio Suite to generate and export multiple far-field images. I followed this tutorial about building a patch antenna in CST Studio to get the general design.
The goal is to scale the patch length and width, rebuild the project, run the solver, and then export the far-field plots as images.
'Language "WWB-COM"

Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    ' Define and initialize variables
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim scalingFactor As Double
    Dim project As Object
    Dim exportPath As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim SL, SW, SH, Mt, PL, PW, ML, MW, InL, InW, k As Double

    ' Initialize the CST project
    Set project = CreateObject("CSTStudio.Application")

    ' Path to save the exported images
    exportPath = "C:\Path\To\Export\Directory\" ' Change this to your desired path

    ' Initialize the base values from your parameter list
    SL = 59
    SW = 76
    SH = 1.5
    Mt = 0.035
    PL = 29.5
    PW = 38
    ML = 14.75 ' This is typically calculated as SL/2 - PL/2
    MW = 2.86
    InL = 9
    InW = 0.74
    k = 5.62

    ' Reset before each execution of this script
    Call StoreParameter("PL", PL)
    Call StoreParameter("PW", PW)

    ' Loop to generate images for different sizes
    For scalingFactor = 0.30 To 0.6 Step 0.10
        ' Calculate new parameters only for the patch length and width
        PL = 29.5 * scalingFactor
        PW = 38 * scalingFactor

        ' Update CST with new parameters
        Call StoreParameter("PL", PL)
        Call StoreParameter("PW", PW)

        ' Rebuild and solve the project
        Call Rebuild
        Call RunSolver()

        ' Export the farfield plot
        fileName = exportPath & "Antenna_Size_" & scalingFactor & ".png" ' Adjusted to export as .png
        With FarfieldPlot
            .Reset
            .Plottype "3d"
            .SetThetaStart 0
            .SetThetaEnd 180
            .SetPhiStart 0
            .SetPhiEnd 360
            .Step 1
            .Step2 1
            .SetPlotMode "directivity"
            .SetScaleLinear True
            .SetLogRange 40
            .EnablePhaseCenterCalculation True
            .SetPhaseCenterComponent "Theta"
            .SetPhaseCenterPlane "both"
            .SetPhaseCenterAngularLimit 30
            Call SelectTreeItem("Farfields")
            .Plot
            .ASCIIExportAsSource fileName
        End With

    Next scalingFactor

    ' Notify completion
    MsgBox "Generation of far-field images completed."
End Sub

The script runs without errors, but it doesn't export any images.
I verified that the paths and filenames are correct.
I consulted the CST Studio Suite documentation.

export method might not be correct:
Instead of .ASCIIExportAsSource, which exports data in ASCII format, you may want to use .ExportPlotImage. This method should directly export the plot as an image (PNG or JPG). Here's how you can adjust it:
.ExportPlotImage fileName, "png", 1920, 1080


.ExportPlotImage is not a valid method or function in CST Studio's VBA Editor. I appreciate you trying to help though.

@Practical1 did you try Call Capture(fileName, "png") method?
